# Could not create a preboot for APFS install while downloading High Sierra

Tags: macos-high-sierra, apfs

I was trying to factory reset my Macbook air as it was too slow and laggy. At the final stage when I was trying to reinstall High Sierra, an error poped up saying that it could not create a preboot forAPFS install. What should I do to fix this?
I can't put an image so I have put a link below for a Google drive image of how my screen looks at the moment.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-KylKvrrekgi6qcQ-XMPM4bhOdsCa57/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.  Other answers on the internet (eg:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8351488

say that the way to solve this is to not format the drive as APFS.  This seems a bit like solving the fact that my first car is broken by driving a second car.  Is it possible to retro-install an APFS file system on older macs, or can this only be done if APFS was installed at the factory?